# geom_bar with x and fill aesthetics by one factor and dodge by a second

Tags: r, ggplot2, position, geom-bar, stat

I have this `data.frame`:

```
df <- data.frame(id = c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),
                 age = rep(c("young", "old"), 3),
                 value = c(20,15,7,5,2,6))
```

I'd like to plot it using `ggplot2`'s `geom_bar` such that the bars are first separated (`dodge`d) by `age` (but with no gaps between them) and then separated by `id` (along the x axis, with gaps), and are colored by `id`.

I'm only familiar with setting either the `aes(x)` argument to `id` and the `fill` argument to `age`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = value)) + 
 geom_bar(aes(fill = age), position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
 theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Or the opposite - the `aes(x)` argument to `age` and the `fill` argument to `id`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = age, y = value)) + 
 geom_bar(aes(fill = id), position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
 theme_minimal()
```

[image]

But what I want is the plot to look like the first one above but only `fill`ed by `id` rather than by `age`.

There's probably a combination `position` and/or `stat`values that get that. Any idea?

Comment: Hi @dan! I took the liberty to rename the "group" variable to "id", to avoid confusion with the `group` argument used in the answer. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You may use the `group` argument in `aes`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = id, y = value)) +
  geom_bar(aes(group = age, fill = id), position = "dodge", stat = "identity") +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]